# Angularjs ng-href Bug?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-href

I came across something strange and wanted to see if anyone had the same problem. I am using Angularjs with the ng-href directive within an ng-repeat as below. The issue I encountered is that if the ng-href tag just contains the {{var}}, it will do nothing.

```
<li ng-repeat="app in apps">   
<a ng-href="{{app.name}}">{{app.name}}</a> <--THIS DOES NOT WORK
</li>
```

If I add a space (or anything else) before or after the {{var}} as illustrated below it links as expected.

```
<li ng-repeat="app in apps">
<!-- NOTE THE BUG? HERE ... without a leading or trailing character, this doesn't work!! -->   
<a ng-href=" {{app.name}}">{{app.name}}</a> <--THIS WORKS (added a leading space)
</li>
```

Am I missing something here? Is this expected functionality? A bug? I tested in Chrome and Firefox with the same result...

Comment: What are the contents of {{app.name}} does it contain a fully qualified URL beginning with http(s)?

Comment: Which version of angular causes this issue.? I cant seem to replicate. http://plnkr.co/edit/K0ESzz?p=preview i dont think the issue mentioned in the thread is what you have

Comment: I am using 1.3.15...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a [ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2755) about this bug. The ticket contains some workarounds and fixes.

Comment: Ah...OK I am glad I am not crazy. Thanks! The workarounds are great...adding the space seems to work as well (it is ignored).